# Can't display Site

Tags: site-collection, access-denied

I Built a SQL server and another server for IIS & SharePoint.

I installed everything without an issue, got to the Central admin page. Created a Web Application, then created a site Collection.

I am unable to open the site.

I got error saying

> This Site has not been shared with you

I set myself and the service account as the site admin. I really don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: Are you accessing the site from server? Under which account you login? What is site collection template? Is that root site collection?

Comment: I access the site from the server and from my desktop.  I use "run as different user" with IE on the server and no luck access the site.  I don't have problem accessing the Central Admin page on either platforms.

Comment: what authentication method you are using? what template you ar ebeing used for the site collections? is it the root site collection of the web app?

Comment: I tried both NTML and Kerberos.  Either of them works.  When setup Kerberos, I asked my network engineers to setup SPN for the account.

Comment: Is it publishing site? Are u using fqdn for webapp?how many site collections u have?

Comment: I created team sites.  I didn't use FQDN for the webapp neither.  (first one url is http://servername, using port 80; the other one is http://servername:16529) so far, I created two Web Apps and one team site for each.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are missing permissions, whether farm, or site collection administrator. Please see the below steps, to ensure you have the correct permissions defined.

Per [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263094.aspx), 
You typically use the Central Administration website to create a site collection in a stand-alone deployment.

1. To create a site collection by using Central Administration
   Verify that you have the following administrative credentials:

   - To create a site collection, you must be a member of the F**arm Administrators** SharePoint group on the computer that is running the SharePoint Central Administration website.
2. Start SharePoint 2013 Central Administration.

   - For Windows Server 2008 R2:

     1. Click Start, click Microsoft SharePoint 2013 Products, and then click SharePoint 2013 Central Administration.
   - For Windows Server 2012:

     1. On the Start screen, click SharePoint 2013 Central Administration.
        If SharePoint 2013 Central Administration is not on the Start screen:
     2. Right-click Computer, click All apps, and then click SharePoint 2013 Central Administration.

For more information about how to interact with Windows Server 2012, see Common Management Tasks and Navigation in Windows Server 2012.

3. On the Central Administration website, in the Application Management section, click Create site collections.
4. On the Create Site Collection page, in the Web Application section, if the web application in which you want to create the site collection is not selected, on the Web Application menu, click Change Web Application, and then click the web application in which you want to create the site collection.
5. In the Title and Description section, type the title and description for the site collection.
6. In the Web Site Address section, select the path to use for your URL (for example, a wildcard inclusion path such as /sites/, or the root directory (/).

If you select a wildcard inclusion path, you must also type the site name to use in your site's URL.

7. In the Template Selection section, in the Select experience version list, select the SharePoint experience version of the templates that you want to use.

Select the 2010 experience version if you want the site collection to look and run like a site collection in SharePoint Server 2010. A site collection that uses the 2010 experience version runs in SharePoint 2013, but the user interface and user experience of the site collection is that of SharePoint Server 2010. A site collection that uses the 2010 experience version can be upgraded at any time to the 2013 experience version. For more information about how to upgrade a site collection, see Upgrade a site collection to SharePoint 2013.

8. In the Template Selection section, in the Select a template list, select the template that you want to use for the top-level site in the site collection, or click the Custom tab to create an empty site and apply a template later.

A description for the template that you select appears below the list of templates.

9. In the Primary Site Collection Administrator section, type the user name (in the form DOMAIN\username) for the user who will be the site collection administrator.
10. In the Secondary Site Collection Administrator section, type the user name for the secondary administrator of the site collection.

Designating a secondary site collection administrator is a best practice to ensure that someone can manage the site collection when a primary site collection administrator is not present.

11. If you are using quotas to manage storage for site collections, in the Quota Template section, click a template in the Select a quota template list.
12. Click OK.

Comment: hum...  I've gone through these steps to setup the Web Application and Site Collections.  I set myself and one of the service account to be the site collection admin.  But, I am not sure where else I need to set permission.

Comment: That should ideally be only locations you would need to add the permissions. Have you tried accessing as both accounts? and does the system account let you access the site?

Comment: Also, you can try the following, if you want to force the specific user account: At any time, you can log in with whatever user account by manually entering the following, enter your domain and subsites and then "/_layouts/accessdenied.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true​".

For example, "http://www.yourdomain.com/subsite/_layouts/accessdenied.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true".

Comment: I get prompt for credentials when append loginasanotheruser=true to the accessdenied.aspx?.  I try again same path but using "default.aspx?" this time.   I am getting this error, "Sorry, something went wrong".

Comment: The prompt for credentials is so you can put in your credentials, and log in as that user. For example, you could try logging in as your service account, and see if you have access. Likewise, you can re-log as your user account. You want to add it to the access denied page, just as a force, to re-log in. This will ensure you log into the site under the right account that has permissions. Please let me know if this helps.